# How to divide lines using html() method in Jsoup

Tags: java, hyperlink, jsoup, element

I'm experiencing one problem catching elements by tag in Jsoup. The return of the method links.html() writen in `String crawlingNode = links.html();` writes in the .txt file an entire string without spaces or line divisions. But, in the console it shows the links divide per line. So, I need to ask **if there is one way to write in the .txt file the links divide per lines using html() method?** Cos for me it doesn't make sense that the returned method on the console shows divided and on the .txt file I can do the same

ps: I'm sorry for not give one shorter version, but the code is complete runnable. Focus on the

```
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("cite");  
            String crawlingNode = links.html();
                crawlingNode = crawlingNode.replaceAll("(?=<).*?(>=?)", ""); //Remove undesired html tags
                    System.out.println(crawlingNode);
                        httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode);
```

part, which contains the problem I want to solve. Thanks in advance!

```
public class httptest {

        static File file;
        File folder= null;
        String crawlingNode, date,  timeZone,Tag="Google Node";
        static BufferedWriter writer = null;
        static httptest ht;

        public httptest() throws IOException{

            date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                folder = new File("queries/downloads/"+date+" "+TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
                    file = new File(folder.getPath()+"\\"+date+" "+Tag+".txt"); 
                        folder.mkdir();

        }

        private void GetLinks() throws IOException{

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/search?q=mamamia")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)")
                        .cookie("auth", "token")
                        .timeout(3000)
                        .get();

                Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("cite");  
                String crawlingNode = links.html();
                    crawlingNode = crawlingNode.replaceAll("(?=<).*?(>=?)", ""); //Remove undesired html tags
                        System.out.println(crawlingNode);
                            httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode);

        }


           private static void OpenWriter(File file){
               try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to open URL Writer");
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }

           }

           private static void WriteOnFile(BufferedWriter writer, String crawlingNode){

               try {

                    writer.write(crawlingNode);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to write URL Node");
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }

           }


           private static void CloseWriter(BufferedWriter writer){
               try {

                    writer.close();

               } catch (IOException e) {

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to close URL Writer");
                    System.err.println(e);

               }
           }

           public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

                ht = new httptest();
                httptest.OpenWriter(file);
                ht.GetLinks();
                httptest.CloseWriter(writer);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try this: WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode+"\n");

Comment: I tried httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode+System.lineSeparator()+"gogogo"); This prints correctly even on the notepad which means the method html returns really one big string which should not contains breaklines...can realise how its showing up in console or in another editors

Comment: If i try to replace the breaklines with crawlingNode.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "GOGO"); nothing happens, which means, there are no breaklines characters =/

Comment: Maybe if you try adding that for statement, you can add a \n to the end of each link. The problem might also be that it thinks the \n is part of the link.

Comment: @Collin I found my answer, check it please =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the strings was not one valid solution. Instead we need to create another string and retrieve its links with the `text()` method; Anyway, the piece of code working for me its below:

```
    Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("cite");  
                String crawlingNode = links.html();
                    crawlingNode = crawlingNode.replaceAll("(?=<).*?(>=?)", ""); //Remove undesired html tags

                    for (Element link : links) {

                    String linkText = link.text()+System.lineSeparator();
                    System.out.println(linkText);
                    httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, linkText);
}
```

Comment: Well done, I'm glad you got it working. This is going into my personal cookbook.

Comment: @Collin could you vote up on the question please? I would like to remove the negativation from one stupid.. =]

Answer (score 1):

The lines in `crawlingNode` are separated with the unix line-separator `\n`. Windows is using `\r\n` so you will have problems to see a linebreak in e.g. Notepad.
You could use a different Editor or replace the separators.

```
crawlingNode.replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))
```

Comment: I bet this is the problem. Try this before you rearrange it into a for statement.

Comment: I tryed what u said and this crawlingNode.replace("\n", System.LineSeparator()); even though  it doesn't work..damn - but I can see in one thing you guys are write, with the wordpad it breaks the lines, so if I want to read the links should I just take the string as an array and then separate the read through /n?

Comment: Oh wait, I went full retard for a second. You are trying to separate the string into separate lines. Try this: httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode+"\n");

Comment: this seems to be a generla problem with notepad - I made one research and a lot of people has this issue

Comment: I found my answer, check it please ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding a for statement in there to scan each element at a time.

```
for(Element link : links)
{
       String crawlingNode = link.html();
       crawlingNode = crawlingNode.replaceAll("(?=<).*?(>=?)", ""); //Remove undesired html tags
       System.out.println(crawlingNode);
       httptest.WriteOnFile(writer, crawlingNode);
}
```

Although I am not 100% sure a single element works with the .html() method. You will have to try it yourself. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: like this it will write all the links and replicate for each link objects hehe I thought this way already =]] but ty

Comment: Whoops. I see you already tried the above suggestions. I honestly thought that would work.

Comment: take a look at what I said hehe =]